# Merge outputs into one list in Prolog

Tags: merge, prolog

I have a prolog assignment that requires us to make a list of all the pairs of numbers in the range of two givens. I can get it to output (using one function) the following, but I don't know how to merge all the outputs. Here is the outbut of calling the function:

```
?- i(L,5,7).
L = [(5, 5),  (5, 6),  (5, 7)] ;
L = [(6, 5),  (6, 6),  (6, 7)] ;
L = [(7, 5),  (7, 6),  (7, 7)] ;
```

And here is the code (the interval methods are prof defined and not allowed to modified):

```
interval(X,L,H) :-
    number(X),
    number(L),
    number(H),
    !,
    X>=L,
    X=<H.

interval(X,X,H) :-
    number(X),
    number(H),
    X=<H.

interval(X,L,H) :-
    number(L),
    number(H),
    L<H,
    L1 is L+1,

    interval(X,L1,H).

i(L,X,Y):-
    interval(N2,X,Y),
    setof((N2,N),interval(N,X,Y),L).
```

I am looking for the output to be this instead:

```
L = [ (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
i(L,X,Y):-
    interval(N2,X,Y),
    setof((N2,N),interval(N,X,Y),L).
```

Will **first set `N2`** to a number in the interval, and next you ask to generate a set for that given number `N2` and a variable number `N`.

You can however simply define a composite in the goal of `setof/3`:

```
i(L,X,Y) :-
    setof((N2,N),(interval(N2,X,Y),interval(N,X,Y)),L).
```

Nevertheless, perhaps a more elegant way to do it (an probably more *Prolog*) is to define an `interval_tuple/3` predicate:

```
interval_tuple(X,Y,(N,N2)) :-
    interval(N,X,Y),
    interval(N2,X,Y).
```

and then call your `setof/3` or `listof/3` on that predicate:

```
i(L,X,Y) :-
    listof(Tup,interval_tuple(X,Y,Tup),L).
```

Comment: Thanks! I was guessing it was something simple that my sleep deprived brain was overlooking.

Comment: Not sure if you should call `(X, Y)` a tuple. It is (well, it's `','(X, Y)`), but then `(X, Y, Z)` is not a "tuple" as in Python or Haskell, for example (because it is `','(X,','(Y,Z))`, not `','(X, Y, Z)`).

Comment: @Boris: but actually you canot call `[1,2]` a list, it is `|(1,|(2,[]))`. There exist no "real datastructures" in Prolog. Prolog is untyped so it means datastructures only exist because programmers say these are.

Comment: Didn't want to get preachy, just pointing out that you would never see `(X, Y)` in library code. It would be `X-Y` (a pair), or `point(X, Y)`, and so on. Also: a Prolog **is** a "list", it would be easier to argue that it is not an "array", maybe.... As for types and datastructures, there is much to disagree about in the last sentence of your comment but it is beside the point :-)

Comment: @Boris: no `[1,4]` is only syntactical sugar for functors. Most Prolog libraries indeed treat them as lists, but you can treat them like you want. For instance `X-Y` is not per se a pair, nor is it subtraction, or a difference list. The semantics of functors are free. If I implemented an alternative `is/2` where `X-Y` means multiplication, that would be fine (but raise some eyebrows) :)

Comment: PS: the only place you would see something like `(X, Y)` is when you are actually trying to do something with conjunctions. For example, somewhere [in here](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pllib.htm) you can find the following example of using `foldl` to make a conjunction out of a list of goals: `flip_conj(Goal, (Goal,Conj), Conj).

?- foldl(flip_conj, [p,q,r], Conj, true).
=> Conj = (p, q, r, true).`

Comment: In C, you use `struct`s and pointers to make data structures. In Prolog, you use terms to make data structures. It is a bit unfair to start claiming that there are no lists or data structures in Prolog. It would be as saying that loops don't exists because it is just conditional GOTOs.

Comment: @Boris: but you propose to use a "pair", you say `X-Y` is a pair, it is simply `-(X,Y)`, the *semantics of functors* in Prolog are completely free, so `X-Y` is as much a pair as `(X,Y)` or `X/Y` or `[X,Y]`. It's all by convention that something is called a list. The most minimal Prolog interpreter with no builtin predicates does not have to know what a list is, whereas the most minimal C-compiler should know what an array is, because that case is special.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that `X/Y` is a pair does not negate the fact that `X-Y` is a pair, or `point(X,Y)` is a pair, or even `[X,Y]`. All hold a pair of variable references inside. `X-Y` doesn't have to be a subtraction or a difference, but it can't not be a pair. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this concisely with CLP(FD):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)]).

interval(Left, Right, (X,Y)) :-   % Definition of one interval
    [X, Y] ins Left .. Right,
    label([X, Y]).

intervals(Left, Right, IntervalList) :-
    Left #=< Right,
    label([Left, Right]),
    findall(Interval, interval(Left, Right, Interval), IntervalList). % Find all intervals
```

I'm using the more descriptive name, `intervals/3` rather than simply `i/3`. I've also reordered the arguments a bit.

Comment: Use rather `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).`